# How to speed up webpack development

Tags: npm, webpack

## The Question:

Is there any way to also set up webpack to work in a *fast developement* mode?

If only it could be like editing files without a bundler. Make a change - view in browser immediately.

#### A bit of context:

As far as I know, the goal of using webpack is to pack what you need into as few files as possible and be able to cleanly `require()` across .js files, but it has the large downside of taking anywhere form a few seconds to mutliple minutes in order to build it, completely destroying a developers headspace when trying to view quick changes.

#### Specific details of a slow webpack set up:

I have been using a weback.config made by a colleague which combines and uglifys files and packages with the goal of having modulare js and a fast production website:

**Webpack.config:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "none",
  entry: {
    "physiomeportal": "./src/index.js",
    "physiomeportal.min": "./src/index.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: 'physiomeportal',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(html)$/, use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]},
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader:"file-loader",
        query:{
          name:'[name].[ext]',
          outputPath:'images/' }
      },
      { test: /\.(vs|fs)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'raw-loader'
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: true
      }
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.$": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

I been using `npm run build` every time I wish to see changes to a file that uses `require()`

Comment: Create a dev-only config, which removes everything you don't have to have during development and use webpack-plugin-serve (or similar) to serve those files and have HMR support. By doing so, you'll have a much faster build.

Comment: Thanks @PlayMa256. I'm using [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) and it still takes nearly just as long to compile. Is there any way to only recompile changes made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Webpack-dev-server

Start with using [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server).

It has an option for '*hot reloading*', where only changed elements of your app will be rebuilt. It aims to adjust in browser without refreshing but depending on your app, that functionality doesn't always work.

#### Install it using

`npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

#### Add it to your webpack.config

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "start:hotdev": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
  ...
}
```

#### Run it

```
npm run start:hotdev
```

Comment: 2021 Update: my workplace switched to vue.js a few years ago which comes with webpack dev servers out of the box. Most frameworks in 2021 will